# Show partition in under "Devices" in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, fstab, udev

I have an external USB stick and HDD that used to be listed under "Devices" in Nautilus and I was able to mount/unmount them by clicking on them. For some reason, they aren't listed any more...

The output of `blkid` with both inserted is:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="RM-CM-)servM-CM-) au systM-CM-(me" UUID="3C80725A80721A9A" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Data" UUID="3ED8A960D8A91765" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows 7" UUID="EEB24EBCB24E88D3" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="b4129786-98de-46ce-81c8-2a9a132ef09e" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda6: UUID="199c03cc-403c-400a-8805-d58275d87df5" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="USB_FAT32" UUID="4144-9B8B" TYPE="vfat"
```

*So how do I fix this?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `blkid&&sudo parted --list`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. (Please help us help you!) Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't know if this is relevant, but I often get "random" kernel panics or other problems when booting, restarting or waking up from sleep/hibernate on this particular laptop which do not occur on another running the same ubuntu so there may be some problematic hardware (probably graphics card from what I've read). Thanks for the help by the way :)

Comment: Those are totally different questions better asked as separate questions. can you try and `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and change `ntfs` by `ntfs-3g`  in your fstab?

Comment: ntfs-3g is already the newest version, and I still get the error message after switching ntfs-3g in the fstab.

Comment: Can you change `uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,sync,auto,rw` to  `defaults,noexec,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8` in fstab?

Comment: Done.  Now it doesn't automount so it doesn't appear in Devices unless I mount it manually in command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38321/discussion-between-fabby-and-mwa1).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? If so, can you post an answer to your own question?

Comment: I didn't solve it, I just fresh installed 16.04